# maven deploy into local repository

Tags: maven, nexus

Can somebody, please, point me to the way of how can I deploy artefacts into the local repository to test deploy scenario? The thing is that we use nexus as remote repository and I wonder if it is possible to deploy my artifacts with custom name and not with names which nexus provide for us.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the following command

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=myfile.jar -DgroupId=com.example -DartifactId=myartifact -Dversion=0.1 -Dpackaging=jar
```

`myfile.jar` is your artifact and the meaning of `-DgroupId`, `-DartifactId` etc. is obvious too.

See documentation [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html).

In case you needed a remote repository as well, see `mvn deploy:deploy-file`([here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-remote.html))